# C# converting binary to text -- question marks?

Tags: c#, text, unicode, binary, converters

I'm converting a binary file to text and dumping it into a PDF.  I have this working, but I need to produce output that is identical to some samples of another program in a different language (it makes the text, then converts it to binary, so I guess I'm converting back?).

I get identical output except for one thing.  I should have a bunch of dashes to set off subject headers, but instead I'm getting question marks (`?`).  If I use Notepad++ to display the binary file, the question marks turn into some random Korean character (`컴`).  I've tried doing `result.Replace("?", "-");` and `result.Replace("컴", "-");` and I've even tried checking with `Contains()`, but nothing is triggered.

How can I replace them?

Not sure if it will help, but here's my code:

```
private void btnConvertBinaryToPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(); //make new pdf document
        PdfPage page = document.AddPage(); //add a page to the document
        XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page); //use this to draw/write on the specified page
        XFont font = new XFont("Courier New", 10); //need a font to write with

        string result = "";
        string path = @"C:\Users\file";

        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        UTF8Encoding temp = new UTF8Encoding(true);
        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);
        int i = 1; 
        while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
        {
            string tmp = temp.GetString(b);
            result += tmp;
            b = new byte[1024]; //clear the buffer 
        }


        if (result.Contains("?"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("contains!");
        }
        result.Replace("컴", "-");

        XTextFormatter tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);
        XRect rect = new XRect(40, 100, 500, 100);
        tf.DrawString(result, font, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);

        string filename = "HelloWorld.pdf"; //make the filename
        document.Save(filename); //save the document to the filename
        Process.Start(filename); //open the file to show the document
    }
```

EDIT: `path` contains binary data.  I need to get the text representation of its contents.  The above works fine, except in the case of ASCII characters numbered higher than 127.

Comment: Question marks tends to be caused by text encoding problems.  This starts off badly, utf-8 is a variable-length encoding.  The way you are using FileStream will cut off part of the byte(s) that encode a character.  You *must* use StreamReader to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're simply making a mess of reading from the file. I'll assume that `path` contains text data; in which case, you might be better off simply using:

```
string result = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

optionally specifying an encoding:

```
string result = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF8);
```

At the moment, you are:

- treating more bytes as data than you read each iteration
- not handling partial character reads

(there are also some inefficiencies in how you handle the `string`, the `byte[]` and the `FileStream`, but frankly that is moot if you're also getting the wrong answer)

Finally, your replace: *does nothing*:

```
result.Replace("컴", "-");
```

should be:

```
result = result.Replace("컴", "-");
```

(if it is still needed)

Comment: `path` doesn't contain text data, it contains binary data, which is why I didn't use `string result = File.ReadAllText(path);` in the first place.  The only thing I'm getting wrong is that I should see `---------------Statistics--------------` and see `?????????????Statistics???????????????` instead.

Comment: @senschen if it doesn't contain text, **why are you using `Encoding.GetString()`**? that makes no sense. What is the data here?

Comment: The data is definitely binary --I was trying to get the string representation of the contents of `b` there.

Comment: @senschen yeah, that's not a valid thing to do

Comment: @senschen it can **only** "work fine" if the data is UTF8. Otherwise the results are completely undefined.